# Insert multiple null values in sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to insert multiple null values in a sql table.Can some body help in the below query

```
UPDATE PDetail
SET rText = null AND ctnumber = null AND ptext = null
WHERE rText = 'For help' OR ctnumber = '123654789'  

INSERT INTO PDetail (rText,ctnumber,ptext) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL)
WHERE rText = 'For help' OR ctnumber = '123654789'
```

Comment: control-C + control-V ?

Comment: mySQL or SQL server? and are there any constraints on PDETAIL (Such as any field being a primary key or having a unique index which would prevent you from doing what you're wanting?)

Comment: its sql server 2008. there is a p.key and f.key in the table. does will impact while inserting null values?

Comment: On an insert yes.  as you can't duplicate the primary keys; and a primary key can't be null.  It can however be null on a unique index, but only one record can contain a null value in the primary key field.  I guess where I'm confused is you say you want to insert multiple null values... but it seems like you're trying to update which is it and what conditions are needed for the update? M.Ali seems close. if it is infact an update statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update values, not insert since you are changing values for already existing records in your table using a where condition in your query. do something as follows ...

```
UPDATE PDetail 
SET rText    = null
   ,ctnumber = null 
   ,ptext    = null
WHERE  rText = 'For help'  
OR     ctnumber = '123654789'
```

Comment: all total table values are set to null when i executed as abv

Comment: I have only fixed the UPDATE statement for you, I dont know what data you have in your table maybe you wanted to update rows `WHERE rText = 'For help' AND ctnumber = '123654789'`. Use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

--here's 50 assuming no constraints...

```
INSERT INTO PDetail  (rText,ctnumber,ptext) VALUES 
(
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL)
);
```

This seems really odd though why do you need to insert 50 records of null values?

Comment: some number were changed so i need to update it as abv in my table